# Does OpenBSD use bcrypt by default?

Tags: password, encryption, openbsd

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

with what does OpenBSD store the password by default?

They say bcrypt is way more secure then hashing. I googled' it and obsd supports bcrypt, but does it use it by default?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: http://www.openbsd.org/papers/bcrypt-paper.pdf

```
We have implemented bcrypt and deployed it as part
of the OpenBSD operating system. Bcrypt has been
the default password scheme since OpenBSD 2.1
```

Comment: From: http://www.eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index/pdf/Security%20Evaluation%20of%20the%20OpenBSD%20Operating%20System.pdf Bcrypt takes the password and (a) uses a 128 bit salt (b) a cost value, (c) use **localcipher** to encrypt. The **localcipher** is defined by login.conf and by default is Blowfish.